# Qt Compass - problems with QMagnetometer

Tags: android, qt

As Qt is not supporting the QCompass class on Android,
I decided to build my own compass app.

I translated the needed Java classes into c++ for building a compass app with the accelerator and magnetometer sensors.

---

You can find the following code snippet in the getRotationMatrix java method:

```
 public static boolean getRotationMatrix(float[] R, float[] I,
 float[] gravity, float[] geomagnetic) {
 // TODO: move this to native code for efficiency
 float Ax = gravity[0];
 float Ay = gravity[1];
 float Az = gravity[2];
 final float Ex = geomagnetic[0];
 final float Ey = geomagnetic[1];
 final float Ez = geomagnetic[2];
 float Hx = Ey*Az - Ez*Ay;
 float Hy = Ez*Ax - Ex*Az;
 float Hz = Ex*Ay - Ey*Ax;
 final float normH = (float)Math.sqrt(Hx*Hx + Hy*Hy + Hz*Hz);
 ----> if (normH < 0.1f) {
 // device is close to free fall (or in space?), or close to
 // magnetic north pole. Typical values are  > 100.
 return false;
            }
    ...
```

My problem is that “if (normH < 0.1f) “ is always false. (I just added an arrow in the code to show you the line).

In my opinion the problem is that the magnetometer sensor returns values like this:

- magn[]={ -6.9375e-06 , -9.125e-06 , 6.25e-06 }
- magn[]={ -6.6875e-06 , -9.375e-06 , 6.5e-06 }
- magn[]={ -6.1875e-06 , -9.375e-06 , 6.5e-06 }
- magn[]={ -5.9375e-06 , -8.875e-06 , 6.5e-06 }
- magn[]={ -5.6875e-06 , -9.375e-06 , 6.75e-06 }
- magn[]={ -5.6875e-06 , -9.125e-06 , 6.75e-06 }
- magn[]={ -5.9375e-06 , -8.875e-06 , 6.25e-06 }
- magn[]={ -5.9375e-06 , -8.875e-06 , 6.5e-06 }
  …

with the acceleration values:

- accel[]={ -2.10605 , 0.919373 , 9.61426 }
- accel[]={ -2.1435 , 0.880215 , 9.65342 }
- accel[]={ -2.1435 , 0.880215 , 9.61426 }
- accel[]={ -2.10605 , 0.842759 , 9.65342 }
  …

normH is always something around this: normH = 0.000110721
So the getRotationMatrix function will always return false.

Info:

- I’m using the QMagnetometer for the values shown as magn[]=…
- setReturnGeoValues doesnt change something.
- The magn values are with setReturnGeoValues(true).

My questions are:

- Is the magnetometer working properly?
- Do I have to convert the “tiny” values into a different “electromagnetic unit” or something else?
- => How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Qt returns values in T and native Android returns values in µT.

I just wrote an native Android Magnetometer app to verify that my sensor is working.
Android returns values like: 3.??? or 5.???.
Qt returns values like: 3.???e-06 or 5.???e-06